# php in resultStr in callback jquery function, not working

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, view, callback

I have a view, the controller renders the view sending some data, example $sizes.
In the view I have a jquery function that based on form post retrieves objects from database and returns a json response.
in the callback function I append a resultStr so to update the view with the item I got from the database.
the problem was I am using laravel and blade and blade doesn't get parsed if the script is separated from the view.
So I thought, ok I will have the resultStr use plain php instead but it doesn't work either.
For example I put this code in the callback function:

```
resultStr = resultStr +

      "<?php " +
      "foreach ($possible_sizes as $size){" +
      "print(\" {$size[\"it\"]} \")}" +
      " ?>";

$("#results").html(resultStr);
```

but then what I get in my div is not the data but this line:

```
<div id="results">

<!--?php foreach ($possible_sizes as $size){print(" {$size["it"]} ")} ?-->

</div>
```

question is: why?

example of code in script.js

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var form = $('form');
            form.submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: form.prop('action'),
                    type: 'post',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: form.serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {

                        var obj = (data);
                        var resultStr = "";
                        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {

                            resultStr = resultStr + 
                            "string to be" + 
                            "inserted in the #results" +
                            "div and containing php code" +
                            "to be executed in the view";


                        }

                        $("#results").html(resultStr);

                    }

                })
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: php has to be executed before it reaches the browser. You cant dynamically write php with javascript. It doesnt work that way.

Comment: PHP doesn't run *in the browser*.  That first block of code looks like it's basically one giant syntax error.

Comment: The first block of code is just assembling some text it's not executing any php, it's a string that is inserted in the result div in the view and it's php. If I keep this script in the view (using blade) and not separated in a js file it works.

Comment: Blade renders before the javascript. So that's why you get a string and not the php functionality you're looking for.

Comment: @Chriz74: Then I'm surprised that the interpreter is ignoring the `<?php ?>` block.  It kind of makes me suspect that the page isn't being processed by the PHP interpreter at all, which renders the whole concept further moot if PHP isn't even running.  Either way, it doesn't really matter.  In order to dynamically fetch data from the server you're going to need to make AJAX requests to the server.  You can't put PHP code in the browser and expect it to work.  (Imagine a world where users could execute their own code *on your server* from their browsers...)

Comment: @SantiagoMendozaRamirez please look at the code, I am not using blade in this case.

Comment: @david the ajax request is done and is returning some items, but then I need to fill my div with all the items the server returned based on sizes, hence the foreach loop. Imagine something like foreach size show me the item. the sizes are not returned by the ajax request, they are there in the view, passed by the controller at first. the ajax request is done through a form.

Comment: @Chriz74: If the sizes aren't returned by the AJAX request then you can't exactly loop through them on the client, can you?  You can only operate on data that you have available.  The sizes would either need to be returned by the request, or returned by a separate request, or included in the page's data when it's initially loaded.

Comment: You can't append php code from javascript dinamically. Just loop the data with javascript and append it with it. There are several ways to do it, includings renderers.

Comment: @David Maybe I didn't make myself clear. The controller returns a view WITH $sizes, the sizes are there. Then I make the ajax request and get some objects. After that foreach object the request returned I create a new form with the picture of the item (`obj[i].picture`) and under that I need a selector with the sizes, so the loop I need to show the sizes under the obj picture. This works perfectly if I leave the script in the view even using blade but if I put the js in a separate file blade doesn't parse stuff like `@foreach` anymore and so I need to create the string with plain php.

Comment: @Chriz74: `"but if I put the js in a separate file"` - What separate file?  If this is just a `.js` file referenced by your page then it's *probably* not being processed by any server-side code.  `.js` files just contain JavaScript code.

Comment: @Chriz74: And at what point in the execution of the page does `script.js` get processed by a PHP interpreter?  (And, if you manage to get it to be processed by a PHP interpreter, that first block of code is, again, going to be one giant PHP syntax error.)  You're trying to mix client-side code and server-side code.  PHP doesn't work like that.

Comment: please check the code I added in the question. I am not trying to make javascript interpret php. I am just preparing a string that will be inserted in the div by the javascript callback function and that string contains php that should be run in the browser in the view. And again, this works if the script is left in the view file instead of a script.js file called in the view.

Comment: @Chriz74: `"that string contains php that should be run in the browser"` - You clearly haven't listened to *anything* we've been saying in these comments.  *PHP doesn't run in the browser.*  Server-side code runs on the server, client-side code runs on the client.  No matter how much you want that to change, it isn't going to.

Comment: @David, please let me understand. If I have a view with some data and in the view I put a <?php foreach ($data as $i) { // something } ?> then the php will not work? In which universe? This is exactly what I am trying to do here and I am telling you that it works if that script I added to the question is put inside the view.

Comment: @Chriz74: Yes, when you put PHP code in your `.php` file, that code is executed by the server.  Nobody here has suggested otherwise.  But that's *not* what you're trying to do here.  You are trying to do two *completely different things*.  One works, the other doesn't.  Both for very good reasons.  Given your fundamental misunderstandings of how PHP works, you might want to walk through some introductory tutorials and play around with the language a bit in some much simpler scenarios.  A stronger understanding of the basics is really going to help you in the long run.

Comment: my view IS a php file, infact what I am doing is simply inserting more php in the div that's inside the php view. Anyway since it seems I don't get the point can you tell me how would you create that data in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the long comment thread above, it seems the answer is...

You have a PHP page which is referencing a `.js` file.  In that separate `.js` file you have the following:

```
resultStr = resultStr +
      "<?php " +
      "foreach ($possible_sizes as $size){" +
      "print(\" {$size[\"it\"]} \")}" +
      " ?>";

$("#results").html(resultStr);
```

There is a series of significant problems here...

1. JavaScript runs on the client, *after* the server-side (PHP) code **has already been processed**.  You can't inject more PHP code client-side because the server isn't going to process it.  To the browser, this is just text.  Nothing will actually execute it.
2. Even if you want to execute the PHP code before injecting its *results* into your HTML, `.js` files aren't processed by the server-side PHP interpreter.  You *might* be able to configure that differently, but I really wouldn't recommend it.  Keep the PHP in the `.php` pages.  If you want to inject a value into the JavaScript, render that value in a `script` block on the page and use it to invoke functionality in the `.js` file.
3. Even if you do configure your server to process PHP in `.js` files, this PHP code is going to be one giant syntax error.  JavaScript can't be used to build PHP code like this.  (It can be used to build strings which *look like* PHP code, but in the browser those are just strings.)

PHP code is processed first, **once**, on the **server**.  The *results* of that code are sent to the browser as a web page.  From the moment the page loads in the browser, PHP is **done**.  You can make further AJAX requests to the server to invoke further PHP operations and get the results of those operations.  But you can't run PHP code *in the browser*.

Comment: ok that clarifies, so the php that I am inserting dinamically simply doesn't get executed. So there must be a way to make the script create the html and pass it to the view, no? Create all the boxes I need in the callback function and append them in the div.

Comment: @Chriz74: Your JavaScript can generate HTML code and inject that, sure.  If the generation of that code relies on server-side data then you would need to supply that data to the JavaScript somehow.  Either by putting it in a JavaScript variable when your page loads (a variable which is then used by this JavaScript code), or by making an AJAX request to the server to get the data it needs.